# How to move all notes in the Cubase MIDI editor one octave up?

Tags: midi, cubase

I have a rather long bass track that I want to play one octave up. I want every note to change to one octave up. For smaller chunk of notes I can select many and just drag them but it's not working in zoomed out mode for many many notes. Is there a function that can move many notes for me. I use Cubase and its MIDI editor.

Comment: This is possible depending on the software you're using.

Comment: @BartArondson Thanks. I use Cubase and its MIDI editor. It works to move smaller chunks of notes but when there is a large chunk that I must zoom out on I can't move the large chunk upwards in the Cubase MIDI editor. Can I select them all and do + or likewise on the entire note block?

Comment: Not sure about Cubase but in the Piano roll editor on Logic you can `select all` and drag the notes up or down.

Comment: Feel free to make an answer out of this if it works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dhz5zxHe5dI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cubase (C4 on my PC) allows you to insert a track fx for midi tracks that lets you globally raise all notes up or down as many semitones as you want: -

[image]

I've got acoustic piano track fx, transpose feature circled. Maybe this will let you do what you need.

If you only need to apply this to a section of the track you can set up a control track where you only apply transpose in certain areas.